# Where is the discussof register callback and run callback in ros design

Tags: ros, ros2

I remember I have read the article about ros client’s register callback and action callback design in ros document. It discusses different ways to register the callback and run callback. Also, it can use poller to get callbacks to run or use trigger to run callbacks. I want to find it.

Comment: Please edit your post and tags to be clear whether you are asking about ros1 or ros2. The implementations/APIs are *completely* different.

Comment: I remember it is a article talk about the future design of ros. I think it not both ros1 or ros2. But maybe it is in ros2's relational document.

Answer (score 0):

Your description of the content that you're looking for is not really specific enough to find a specific set of documentation. You'll need to be more specific to get more than a guess.

The main things that come to mind are the executor documentation: https://docs.ros.org/en/rolling/Concepts/Intermediate/About-Executors.html

Or the actionlib tutorials: http://wiki.ros.org/actionlib_tutorials/Tutorials

Comment: If not specified otherwise I would suggest to link to the latest ROS2 version documentation, which currently is [ROS2 Iron Irwini](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/index.html).

Comment: I've linked to rolling version as into the future it will be the most likely to be helpful for future readers.